# Visualize difference between 2 classifiers

Tags: classification, data-visualization, python, random-forest, cart

I trained 2 binary classifiers with the same data (a Decision Tree and a Random Forest).

They both made a prediction on the same test data.

Now, I want to visualize the difference in classification between these 2 classifiers. (using Python)

I already came up with this:

```
x = #[List of IDs]
y1 = #[List of predictions from Decision Tree]
y2 = #[List of predictions fro Random Forest]

plt.scatter(x, y1, color='r')
plt.scatter(x, y2,  color='b')
plt.xlim(xmin=890, xmax=1300)
plt.ylim(ymin=-1, ymax=2)
plt.yticks(np.arange(2), ('Class 0', 'Class 1'))
plt.xlabel('ID')
plt.ylabel('Class')
plt.show()
```

This gives the following result:

[image: plot]
[image: zoomed]

As can be seen, the plot is not very clear.

Any suggestions on how I can improve this plot? Or a different way to plot this concept?

Comment: Plotting against identifier will even at best only help if the identifier is informative. You don't tell us anything about your identifiers but in many datasets the identifiers are essentially arbitrary. Isn't the focus of comparison whether the classifiers agree or disagree, generally, and specifically given what data were used? The first is a 2 x 2 table: a graph does no harm but may not help over the table. The second depends on what you used here.

Comment: Note the advice in the Help Center about software-specific questions. Software choices and details are relevant here only in so far as they raise statistical questions.

Comment: In my case, I think the identifiers are informative, they tell if a person is dead or alive. Could you explain the rest of your answer a bit more?

Comment: Does identifier being 901 or 1249 mean anything to you? That's the question. 2 x 2 table: agree 1/1, agree 0/0, disagree 0/1, disagree 1/0. Then you need to relate each outcome to whatever you used in your classifier.

Comment: Is this the same as the True Positives, False Positives, True Negatives and False Negatives?

Comment: That's correct: same thing, different guises. In your case, it is not clear that you can talk about true or false as the nub of the matter appears to be agreement between two methods.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to compare classifiers is to plot the [ROC curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic). It is easy enough to code and gives you a complete view of the performance of the classifiers for all different thresholds.